# Show selected items only from a list jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of cars, currently they are all displayed on the page.

The funcationality I am after is when I click on a car group in the submenu eg A1, only the cars associated with that car group should be displayed. and the rest should be hidden.

Any help is appreciated.

**HTML:**

> ```
> <div id="menu-strip">
>     <ul class="nav nav-pills hr">
>
>         @foreach (var item in Model.ModelGroups)
>         {
>
>             <li class="active">
>
>                 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="menu-item" data-modelid=@item.ModelGroupID>@item.Description</a>
>
>             </li>
>
>         }
>
>     </ul>
> </div> }
> ```

Comment: Please include your html.

Comment: Please also post some HTML and if possible the corresponding code in JSFiddle.

Comment: can you post the corresponding generated HTML..?

Comment: Hi guys, I managed to figure it out in the end. The div class="" was named different to what the JQuery was looking for. It is no longer "submenu-item". this is why it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of thing with classes.

So you give the elements with the cars this sort of HTML structure:

```
<div class="mercedes car"> Merc 1 </div>
<div class="bmw car"> BMW 1 </div>
<div class="bmw car"> BMW 2 </div>
<div class="mercedes car"> Merc 2 </div>
<div class="mercedes car"> Merc 3 </div>
```

You can then have a menu like this:

```
<div class="menu-item" data-car="mercedes">Mercedes</div>
<div class="menu-item" data-car="bmw">BMW</div>
```

And then your JS could be:

```
jQuery('.menu-item').on('click', function (e) {
   jQuery('.car').hide(); // Hide all cars
   var carClass = jQuery(this).attr('data-car');
   jQuery('.' + carClass).show(); // Show the car brand we want
});
```

Comment: Alas, I did not know this existed. Excellent, thank you.